# Is there a ESLint rule to recommend using a?.b?.c instead of a.b.c to avoid some error

Tags: javascript, eslint

In my project, there is a lot of getters like `a.b.c` to get the c prop from a, but sometimes it does not have b prop in a, so my app is crashing. I know  the `lodash/get` is the right way to avoid this problem, but there is a couple of people working together on the project and everyone has different writing style. So I was wondering if there is ESLint rule to do following:

1. scan the code like `a.b.c`
2. report to change a safer way to get prop

Comment: You want to always use optional chaining? I'm not sure this is a good approach.

Comment: The only core ESLint rule regarding optional chaining is https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unsafe-optional-chaining

Comment: I somehow think that you introduce more problems if ESLint enforces optional chaining in every situation.

Comment: I don't have the time, but taking the source of the https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/2774043e6bc0b5709df02ac6bb61be6ac950f77d/lib/rules/no-unsafe-optional-chaining.js could help with making your own rule for optional

Comment: it does not a good approach. because we may not find the data problem.so i suuggest the config provide the ability to config length maybe
a.b.c  is ok
a.b.c.d.f is recommd not ok

Comment: @Tschallacka thanks a lot and help a lot. i will look the code to get some idea.